# GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to directory.users.photos.update failed with error: Invalid Input: photoData When setting user profile picture

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-api

I'm trying to create a google app script attached to a spreadsheet that can set a google user's profile picture.  According to the documentation, this should work:

```
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
var photoBlob = response.getBlob();
var data = Utilities.base64EncodeWebSafe(photoBlob.getBytes());
AdminDirectory.Users.Photos.update({photoData: data}, this.email);
```

However this causes an exception:

```
GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to directory.users.photos.update failed with error: Invalid Input: photoData
```

The user running this script has permission to edit the profile picture

Comment: Did you verify either you retrieved the blob correctly? Try with a photo saved on your Drive first.

Answer (score 0):

There must be a problem with your URL, the following works for me:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var url = "https://www.telegraph.co.uk/content/dam/Pets/spark/royal-canin/tabby-kitten-small.jpg"
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var photoBlob = response.getBlob();
  var data = Utilities.base64EncodeWebSafe(photoBlob.getBytes());
  var email = Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail()
  AdminDirectory.Users.Photos.update({photoData: data}, /*this.*/email);
}
```

Alternatively, you can also use an image from your Drive as following:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var url = "https://www.telegraph.co.uk/content/dam/Pets/spark/royal-canin/tabby-kitten-small.jpg"
  var response = DriveApp.getFileById("1f8EFG6G5zNd6by_fNEecSh2D1My_p-_p")
  var photoBlob = response.getBlob();
  var data = Utilities.base64EncodeWebSafe(photoBlob.getBytes());
  var email = Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail()
  AdminDirectory.Users.Photos.update({photoData: data}, /*this.*/email);
}
```